# Disable delete button from JTextPane

Tags: java, button, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane who works as a Manager for MySQL, so I use it instead of that ugly black and white console. But I wanna know how to disable the 'delete' button after the user press 'Enter' and move to the next line. For example, if I write:

create new database user;

After the user press Enter I don't want them to delete that line of 'Create new database user'.

Thank you guys!

########################## EDIT

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {      

           //***********************************
           se = jTextPane1.getText().toLowerCase();
           String[] linea = se.split("\n");
           String sent = linea[linea.length-1];

           //******************************** 

           String[] validar = sent.split(" ");
      if(validar[0].equals("crear") && validar[1].equals("bd")){
            try {            
                for (int i = 2; i < validar.length; i+=3){
                sentencia.executeUpdate("create database "+validar[i]);
                jTextPane2.setText("Base de Datos "+validar[i]+" Creada");
                    }//for
            }catch (Exception ae) {
            jTextPane2.setText(ae.getMessage());
        }//catch
      }//if
      else{
           jTextPane2.setText("COMANDO MAL INGRESADO");
          }//else
}//ifEnter
```

So what I want is that, after user press 'Enter' and I validate that the first 2 lines are what I need, I execute the Update on MySQL and then move him to the next line of the JTextPane, however, I don't know how to disable the delete button so that if they want to delete everything from the lines before they are right in that moment, they can't. So, what would be the code I have to use?

Comment: You could use a JTextField and then append the entry to a non-editable JTextPane.

Comment: Please provide your current code affecting the question.

Comment: @TheMirrox There's a piece of a code I have. Answer me if you get what I'm asking, sorry if my english is not good enough...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a DocumentFilter (see [the example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/CustomDocumentFilter.htm)) and override methods

```
public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws
                   BadLocationException {
    fb.remove(offset, length);
}

public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
                    AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    fb.replace(offset, length, text, attrs);
}
```

In the methods just check whether `offset/length` are in allowed range and either do nothing to prevent deleting or call super.